# How to change the name of the network interface with ansible?

Tags: ansible, centos7, network-interface

I need to change the name of the network interface using ansible.

eg. 
mv /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1675454  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

nmtui 
and change the profile name

The way that i am doing it currently -

```
 - name: Copy interface file ifcfg-{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }} to ifcfg-etho
  copy: 
    remote_src: True 
    src: '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}'
    dest: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

- name: Replace device name to eth0 inside the file
  replace:
    path: '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'
    regexp:  "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}"
    replace: "eth0"
```

To modify grub:

```
- name: update grub 
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ grub_input_config }}"
    regexp: "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX"
    line: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0" '
  notify: "make grub config"
```

grub handler:

```
---

- name: make grub config
  command: "{{ grub_mkconfig_cmd }} -o {{ grub_output_config }}"
```

defaults

---

```
grub_mkconfig_cmd: grub2-mkconfig
grub_output_config: /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub_input_config: /etc/default/grub
```

Edit: Added code

Comment: Hi @willing_to_learn and welcome to SO (Love your nick by the way :)). What did you try so far and what did not work as expected ? Please take some time to go through the help section, more specifically [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator. I have done the following:
Created a task which copies the current interface file to eth0 and finally replaces the interface name in that file.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to go about?

Answer (score 1):

When you run this ansible tasks and reboot the system, the changes are kept? 
In centos7 i have to do this extra step to make it permanent:

- Edit file /etc/default/grub and add net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 to line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ..."
```

- Regenerate a GRUB configuration file and overwrite existing one:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: HI Diogo, i make changes to GRUB file as well. I forgot to add that part of the code. I have added the code which i use.

Comment: I am able to update the in this way, however it takes a reboot to reflect the change in ifconfig and reconnect the SSH. To make this change effective , is there any workaround other than rebooting the system ?